# Memory hanging around after dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES

Tags: memory, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am presenting a modal view controller which contains a UIScrollView with a bunch of images.  When I dismiss my modal view controller I can see in my Allocations (instruments) that memory assigned to the images is hanging around but not causing leaks.

Causing me some confusion and any help would be great.  Here is what I have...

UIViewController - DollViewController: This is my main view controller that I am presenting my modal over.  Here is the code -

```
-(IBAction)openDollCloset {
    NSLog(@"Open Closet");



    [self playSound:@"soundMenuClick"];
    ClosetViewController *closet = [[ClosetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClosetViewController" bundle:nil];

    closet.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentModalViewController: closet animated: YES];

    closet.delegate = self;
    closet.addToCloset = NO;
    [closet setCurrentDoll:myDoll];
    [closet openCloset];
    [closet release];

    [self closeSubmenu];

}
```

I create my scrollview manually to hold the outfit images.
The object closetScroller is defined with @property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *closetScroller;  with a release in dealloc.

```
- (void)setScrollerValues { 
    if (closetScroller == nil) 
    {
        self.closetScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
        [self.closetScroller setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast];
        [self.closetScroller setDelegate:self];
        [self.closetScroller setPagingEnabled:YES];
        [self.closetScroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:closetScroller];
    }
    [self.closetScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(outfitCount * 320, 400)];
}
```

After creating the scrollView I add the images to the scroller.  I believe I am releasing everything right.  I am creating the images with NSData objects and releasing them.

```
- (void)addOutfitsToScroller {

        // Clear out any old images in case we just deleted an outfit
    if ([[closetScroller subviews] count] > 0) 
    {
        CATransition *fade = [CATransition animation];
        [fade setDelegate:self];
        [fade setType:kCATransitionReveal];
        [fade setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
        [fade setDuration:0.40f];
        [[self.closetScroller subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        [[closetScroller layer] addAnimation:fade forKey:@"FadeButtons"];
    }
        // Set the pageControl to same number of buttons
    [pageControl setNumberOfPages:outfitCount];

        // Load the outfit image and add it to the scroller
    for (int i = 0; i < outfitCount; i++) 
    {
        NSArray *savedDataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[closetItemsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320*i, 0, 320, 400)];
        [v setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [v setAlpha:0.40f];

        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[savedDataArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        UIImage *outfitImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        UIImageView *closetImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:outfitImage];
        [imageData release];
        [outfitImage release];
        [savedDataArray release];

        CGSize frameOffset;
        #ifdef LITE_VERSION
        frameOffset = CGSizeMake(40, 60);
        #else
        frameOffset = CGSizeMake(20, 10);
        #endif
        closetImage.frame = CGRectOffset(closetImage.frame, frameOffset.width , frameOffset.height);

        [v addSubview:closetImage];
        [closetImage release];

        [self.closetScroller addSubview:v];
        [v release];
    }
}
```

This all works great.  Then when the user selects the "Close" button or selects an outfit I call:

```
[self.delegate closeClosetWindow];
```

Which calls the delegate method in the parentViewController which simply makes this call:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I have also tried calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES from the modal view controller itself.  It simply forwards the message to it's parentViewController and closes the modal just the same as the first way.  Neither makes a difference with regards to the memory.

So what I do instead is use this method to close the view:

```
[[self.closetScroller subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When I do that, I can see my Object Allocations decrease in Instruments.  Prior to opening the closet view I have object alloc at about 1.85mb.  When I open the closet it increases to 2.5 or so depending on how many outfit images are loaded into the UIScrollView.  Then when I close the view without the above method it stays at 2.5 and increases the next time I open it.  Although when using the above method that removes the outfit images from the scroller, my object alloc drops back down close the the 1.85mb.  Maybe a little more which tells me it's hanging on to some other stuff also.

Also note that when looking at the object allocations, I do see the ClosetViewController object created and when I close the modal it's refrence is released.  I can see it malloc and free the view as I open and close it.  It's not retaining the view object itself.  i'm so confused.

Not sure what to do here.  I am not getting any leaks and I am releasing everything just fine. Any ideas would be great.

mark

Comment: 'memory' isn't half as useful a tag as something which identified your platform would be.

Comment: sorry, wasn't aware there were a lot of platforms that used UIViewController and ModalViewController other then iphone.  Next time I will be sure to tag it as iPhone iOS4.3 which I hope will help.

Comment: Not allowed to answer own question within 24 hours but I do have the answer.  Noticed object alloc keeping reference to UIScrollView every time I opened modal window.  So to fix, when allocating for my scrollview, I instead allocated a new UIScrollView object and assigned it to closetScroller and then released.  This took care of the problem.

Comment: Oh, and Will.  Feel free to not post a response unless you are answering a question.  I don't care what your rep is here.  If Memory, UIViewController and ModalViewController doesn't do it for you, find some other post to read. Peace.

Comment: Mark A - I didn't post a response, I posted a comment.  If you don't want people who've set StackOverflow to highlight iPhone stuff to them to find your questions, that's fine.

Comment: Will Dean, I see what you are saying and I apologize. After sitting for so long trying to figure this problem out and finally posting a question, I was rather disappointed to see a response that was, to me, completely off topic. But now I do see what you are saying.  I have since looked at the main page and found the way all of this site is organized which is pretty much by platform.  Next time I will definitely add that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I Noticed object alloc in instruments keeping a live reference to UIScrollView every time I opened modal window. So to fix, when allocating for my scrollview, I instead allocated a new UIScrollView object and assigned it to closetScroller and then released. This took care of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you were simply not releasing closetScroller in the dealloc of your view controller.

Comment: I was releasing it as mentioned in the post - The object closetScroller is defined with @property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *closetScroller; with a release in dealloc.  But I went back to check and make sure.  Changed the code back since it was such a small change.  Did the same thing as before.  Still really not sure why though.  It does seem to me that all of the original code should work.  And it never causes a leak.  hmmm.

Comment: Ah, then you should have (auto) released it after assigning it using the accessor in `self.closetScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)]`, right?